# How to add next and previous button to popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have created 2 popup.Inside popup there are two hyperlink  NEXT and PREVIOUS.If any user clicked  on any hyperlink  than next popup should be display according to link.  Please show a quick and simple way to implement this, with javascript/jquery.

Please help me..

**HTML**

```
<a href="#openModal1">Open Modal1</a>

<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">


<div>  <div class="pop-header">
                        <a href="#"> &nbsp; < Previous </a>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
                         <a href="#">Next  ></a>
                        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

                    </div>





                     <div class="row">  

                        <div class="main-content">
                            <div class="col-md-4" ><img src="http://preview.turbosquid.com/Preview/2014/07/11__06_24_26/OpenCardboardBox_2.jpg86a9e6a0-b552-4bfe-8923-71a6f174e5faOriginal.jpg" class="main-logo"/></div>
                             <div class="col-md-8"><h3>Lorem: Ipsum </h3><h4>Lorem: Ipsum</h4>is simply dummy text of the printing Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing </div>
                         </div>

                    </div>

                        <div class="scroll-bar">
                        <div class="main-content">
                         <img src="http://99layer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Demo-website-Swiftlet2.jpg" class="main-img"/>
                        </div>
                         </div>


            </div>


</div>










<a href="#openModal2">Open Modal2</a>

<div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">


<div>  <div class="pop-header">
                        <a href="#"> &nbsp; < Previous </a>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
                         <a href="#">Next  ></a>
                        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

                    </div>





                     <div class="row">  

                        <div class="main-content">
                            <div class="col-md-4" ><img src="http://preview.turbosquid.com/Preview/2014/07/11__06_24_26/OpenCardboardBox_2.jpg86a9e6a0-b552-4bfe-8923-71a6f174e5faOriginal.jpg" class="main-logo"/></div>
                             <div class="col-md-8"><h3>Lorem: Ipsum </h3><h4>Lorem: Ipsum</h4>is simply dummy text of the printing Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing </div>
                         </div>

                    </div>

                        <div class="scroll-bar">
                        <div class="main-content">
                         <img src="http://99layer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Demo-website-Swiftlet2.jpg" class="main-img"/>
                        </div>
                         </div>


            </div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pop-header
    {
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #E0E0E0;
         height: 60px;
         line-height:50px;

    }


    .pop-header > span{
        margin: 10px 20px;
        color:#000;

    }


.pop-header > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
    .modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }


    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 600px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 2% auto;
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #fff;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .close
    {
        float: right;
        padding: 20px;
    }

.main-content
{
    padding: 30px;
}
.main-logo  
{
    height: 130px; 
    width: 130px;

}

.main-img
{

    width: 100%;
    height: 400%;

}
.scroll-bar
{
    width: 98%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-top: 20px;

}
```

Comment: OR you can check this link https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/q1c6hqab/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example works without having to use JQuery or JavaScript.  I am sure you can adapt it to what you need.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Creating a modal window with HTML5 &amp; CSS3</title>

            <style>
                .modalDialog {
                    position: fixed;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    top: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
                    z-index: 99999;
                    opacity: 0;
                    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
                    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
                    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
                    pointer-events: none;
                }

                    .modalDialog:target {
                        opacity: 1;
                        pointer-events: auto;
                    }

                    .modalDialog > div {
                        width: 400px;
                        position: relative;
                        margin: 10% auto;
                        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
                        border-radius: 10px;
                        background: #fff;
                        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
                        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
                        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
                    }

                .close {
                    background: #606061;
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                    line-height: 25px;
                    position: absolute;
                    right: -12px;
                    text-align: center;
                    top: -10px;
                    width: 24px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
                    border-radius: 12px;
                    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
                    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
                }

                    .close:hover {
                        background: #00d9ff;
                    }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>

            <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>
            <a href="#openModal2">Open Modal</a>

            <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                <div>
                    <a href="#openModal2">Next</a>
                    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                    <h2>Modal Box 1</h2>
                    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
                    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
                <div>
                    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                    <a href="#openModal">Previous</a>
                    <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>

                    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
                    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I need little more help.I have created scroll on popup because  there is a big size of image that image is not showing full .You can check this link https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/q1c6hqab/7/

Comment: i want to use the scroll to display the image

Comment: I added a float:right to the cardboard box div. That allowed the text to move up and get rid of a lot of white space.   After that, see if you want to remove the scrollbar

Comment: also did <div class="main-content" style="padding-top:0"> to get rid of even more white space.